# Len function not returning the correct value for string

Tags: python, string-length

So I am trying to call the length of a coded message, and then divide that length by 3 (every 3 chars represents one letter). Here is the message:

```
10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102
```

The dashs are set to be placed directly after spaces, or the letters a, b, or c (because the ord function converts these chars to only 2 digit values and the program requires 3 digits per letter). I have this code:

```
message = (10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102)
message = str(message)
length = len(message)
print(length)
```

The code returns 25 even those the string is 48 chars. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Because you've initiated `message` as an int. You can fix this by putting quotes around it:

```
message = ('10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102')
```

At the moment, converting message to a string afterwards converts it *after* it has performed the minus operations. For example:

```
>>> message = (10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102)
>>> message
-121111117124825601607802
```

As a side-note, the brackets around the assignment are unnecessary. You can just do:

```
message = '10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put that value in ' ' because that number is determined by a variable. So you type in a phrase or message and it encodes it with the ord function.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line

`message = (10311132-10710510810832-121111117114115101108102)`

The expression on the right has been calculated and stored as -121111117124825601607802, which represented as string is 25 characters long.